# Does using Java `CompletableFuture` cause system performance slow down?

Tags: java

I suspect that using CompletableFuture might cause performance issues; when system runs a while (3 days) it becomes slow. Is it possible that `CompletableFuture` is the cause?

Some restful APIs in final step call this method, get information from another API doing background

```java
private void postGetManCardInfoRunAsync(String memberToken) {

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {

        PostGetManCardInfoReq postGetManCardInfoReq = new PostGetManCardInfoReq();
        postGetManCardInfoReq.setMemberToken(memberToken);

        // http client connection
        PostGetManCardInfoRsp resp = cardServiceImpl.postGetManCardInfo(postGetManCardInfoReq);

        Date now = new Date();
        UNYMemberToken unyMemberToken = unyMemberTokenDao.getByMemberToken(memberToken);

        if (unyMemberToken != null) {
            if (!resp.getCardsInfo().isEmpty()) {
                if (resp.getCardInfoSize() > 0) {
                    List<UNYMemberCardInfo> oldCardInfo = unyMemberCardInfoDao
                            .findByMemberTokenGuid(unyMemberToken.getGuid());
                    unyMemberCardInfoDao.delete(oldCardInfo);
                    for (int i = 0; i < resp.getCardInfoSize(); i++) {
                        try {
                            CardInfo cardInfo = resp.getCardsInfo().get(i);
                            unyMemberCardInfoDao.save(unyMemberCardInfo(cardInfo));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            LogHelper.errorNccc(CLASSNAME, "postGetManCardInfo" + "#xxxxxxxx#", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try new Thread().start() instead of runAsync()?

Comment: Not yet, I thought CompletableFuture is better right?, thank you for reply

Comment: If a system becomes slow after running some days it is often a memory problem. If the application is short on memory the GC will run all the time and cause the system to slow down. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) is a good tool to analyze this.

Comment: @Henry what is better, it depends on the goals and environment.